# T-Sql date format for seconds since last epoch / formatting for sqlite input

Tags: t-sql, sqlite, date

I'm guessing it needs to be something like:

```
CONVERT(CHAR(24), lastModified, 101)
```

However I'm not sure of the right value for the third parameter.

Thanks!

---

Well I'm trying to write a script to copy my sql server db to a sqlite file, which gets downloaded to an air app, which then syncs the data to another sqlite file. I'm having a ton of trouble with dates. If I select a date in air and try to insert it, it fails because it's not in the right format... even if it was a valid date to begin with. I figured I'd try to experiment with the unix time since that's the only thing thats worked so far. I am considering just leaving them as varchar because I don't sort by them anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up using format 120 in MS SQL:

```
convert(char(24), lastModified, 120)
```

Each time I needed to a select a date in SQLite for non-display purposes I used:

```
strftime(\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\", dateModified) as dateModified
```

Now I just need a readable/friendly way to display the date to the user!

edit: accept answer goes to whoever shows me how to display the date nicely from sqlite ;p

Comment: Challenge accepted:  Not quite sure what you mean by "display nicely", so I'll guess you mean ...

Comment: not quite sure what i needed this for as it's from 2 and a half years ago

Answer (score 2):

Last epoch is when 1970 GMT?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(s,'19700101 05:00:00:000',lastModified)
```

See also [Epoch Date](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Epoch_Date)

Answer (score 2):

sqlite> **select datetime();**
2011-01-27 19:32:57

sqlite> **select strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','now');**
2011-01-27 19:33:57

**REFERENCE:**
(Date time Functions)[http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html]

Answer (score 0):

Define "last epoch". Does this come close?

Select Cast(lastModified As Integer)

Answer (score 0):

If you store them as varchar, store them as YYYYMMDD. That way you CAN sort by them later if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server has only 2 failsafe date formats

ISO = YYYYMMDD, run this to see that

```
  select convert(varchar(10),getdate(),112)
```

ISO8601 = yyyy-mm-dd Thh:mm:ss:mmm(no spaces) run this to see that

```
select convert(varchar(30),getdate(),126)
```

To learn more about how dates are stored in SQL server I wrote [How Are Dates Stored In SQL Server?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-are-dates-stored-in-sql-server)